# Explicit interface implementation in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

How to implement explicit interface implementation in VB.NET?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

put the method to private.

Comment: MarkJ comment is IMO better, as it explains the context of it.

Answer (score 23):

As [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577149/explicit-interface-implementation-in-vb-net/1577157#1577157) have [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577149/explicit-interface-implementation-in-vb-net/1577173#1577173), make the routine private, and it forces clients to call through the interfaces.

Just one more word. Explicit interface implementation in C# also allows the programmer to [inherit two interfaces that share the same member names and give each interface member a separate implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461(VS.71).aspx). In VB.Net, that's easy, because the implementing methods can have different names from the interface names.

```
Function ICanUseAnyNameILike() As String Implements IFoo.Bar

Function ItsTotalAnarchy() As String Implements IFoo2.Bar, IFoo3.ItsMadnessReally
```

Comment: From here on I'm going to use `IFoo3.ItsMadnessReally` as an interface-method in my projects.

Answer (score 12):

Just declare sub/function `Private`:

```
Private Function Bar() As String Implements IFoo.Bar
```