# Why Assert.AreEqual<T> fails with identical objects?

Tags: c#, assert

I have a class which contains this attributes:

```
public class Person
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? IdCountry { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
    public int? IdState { get; set; }
    public virtual State State { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class State
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int IdCountry { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

In a unit test I create 2 objects with the same values

```
Person expected = new Person()
{
    Name = "blablablbla",
    Id = 1
};
Person actual = PessoaFactory.Create(Name: "blablablbla", Id: 1);
Assert.AreEqual<Person>(expected, actual);
```

But the Assert.AreEqual throws an exception.

Comment: Because Object.Equals() (what will be finally called) will **compare references** (you have classes, not structs) and obviously they're two different objects (two instances). **Override it** if you want to implement some sort of comparison between Person (**what kind of comparison**...well it depends. ID only? All fields? Up to you).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`:

```
public override bool Equals(object o)
{
    if (!(o is Person)) { return false; }
    return ((Person)o).Id == this.Id;
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return this.Id;
}
```

`Assert.AreEqual<T>` uses the default comparer for the type. The default comparer for that type is to compare hash codes. The hash codes aren't equal.

Comment: ...and `GetHashCode()`. We preach best practice where possible.

Comment: You will need to override `GetHashCode()` as well

Comment: @RuiJarimba, you actually don't **have** to `override` the `GetHashCode` method; but it's a good practice so I modified as such. But let's be clear, it does not **have** to be done.

Comment: Just an FYI if the OP is comparing *multiple* properties and not just the ID these need to be taken into consideration in both checks - otherwise `new Person { Id = 1, Name = "Person1" }; new Person { Id = 1, Name = "Person2" }` would be equal (when the OP might not want them to be).

Comment: @James, fair enough; I just didn't want to write out every single property since it's not evident.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud: if you override one of those methods then you should override the other one. The alternative is to use an `IEqualityComparer`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10807365/558486

Comment: @RuiJarimba, I didn't argue the practice; I argued the fact that you stated it was a **necessity.** The statement that it's a **necessity** is wrong. However, I fully agree with the practice and updated my answer to show; did I not? Second, `IEqualityComparer` won't work here because the base `Assert.AreEqual` calls `Equals`.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud: fair enough. Regarding the `IEqualityComparer` - see the link I added.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud sure, plus the OP doesn't really mention whether it is just the ID they are comparing or whether it's a field-level comparison so thought it was worth clarifying.

Answer (score 6):

You need to override `Equals` to compare the objects.  The default implementation compares references, not values.  See the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/336aedhh.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Because it is comparing the *references* not the actual values within it.

Answer (score 2):

You have two different object references to compare.

Instead use `Assert.IsTrue(expected.Id == actual.Id)` for example or override Equals and GetHashCode to be able to compare your objects

Answer (score 0):

The .Net framework itself doesn't handle deep equality cooperation by default, Assert.AreEqual calls the `Equals` method on the object which is `object.Equals` if you didn't override the method. `Object.Equals` is implementing reference check only. You should implement your own Equals method, for example:

```
public override bool Equals(object o)
{
    var cast = o as Person;
    if (cast == null) 
        return false; 
    return cast.Id == this.Id;
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return this.Id;
}
```

For more information you can check this [MSDN Doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/336aedhh.aspx)